# Import a single file from another directory

Tags: python, import, python-import

I'm kind of new with python and there is something troubling me. I'm using pandas to read an excel file. All works well if I have the excel in the same directory as my .py file.

What I want to know is what is the best way to get a file that is in a completely different path. I've searched a lot and haven't found a straightforward answer. I've seen examples with sys.append, examples with external libraries, etc. I am trying to understand the pros/cons as well of each solution. Ideally I would like to have the file path as a user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.path` is where Python tries to locate *modules* or *packages* to **import** them. Not files when you are trying to access them. (like your excel file)

On the other hand, `open` built-in function or Pandas read functions require **a path to a file**. As long as you work with absolute paths you don't need to worry about it.

If you want to give it a relative path, first check to see *where you are* and then locate your file relative to your working directory.

with `os.getcwd()` you can get your current working directory.

As an example, suppose we have:

```
tmp/
└── inside_directory
    ├── pfile.py
    └── text.txt
```

If my terminal indicates that I'm in `tmp` directory and I run my `pfile.py` with:

```sh
python inside_directory/pfile.py
```

and the content of `pfile.py` be:

```py
with open("text.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

I will get error which says: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'`.

Why? because I used relative path and there is no `text.txt` in the `tmp` directory.

#### Then what are the solutions?

**Option-1**: use `open("inside_directory/text.txt")` instead of `open("text.txt")`.

**Option-2**: first go to `inside_directory` then use `open("text.txt")` and run your script with `python pfile.py`.

**Option-3**: Use absolute path. You can access that file regardless of where you are now.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is quite clear. I was mixing the importing of packages/modules and the opening of files which got me confused.